# Algorithm to search words before and after the search string within phrases

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have below array of phrases

```
 const senetences = [
    { "text": "And a moment I Yes." },
    { "text": "Wait a moment I Yes." },
    { "text": "And a moment I Hello, Guenta, trenteuno." },
    { "text": "Okay a moment. Hello. Perfect." },
    { "text": "And a moment." },
    { "text": "And a moment I Hello, Guenta, trenteuno." },
    { "text": "Just a moment in Quinta trenteuno." },
    { "text": "And a moment in Quinta trenteuno." },
    { "text": "Wait a moment I Hello, Guenta, trenteuno." },
    { "text": "Just a moment in Quinta trenteuno." }
  ]
```

Now I search for... suppose `moment`.
So I need to get the some words before and after the exact word `moment` and their matching score in the whole array.

Example output

```
[
  "text": "And a moment", "score": 5, "percent": 50,
  "text": "moment I Hello", "score": 3, "percent": 30,
  "text": "moment in Quinta", "score": 3, "percent": 30,
  "text": "Wait a moment", "score": 2, "percent": 20,
  "text": "moment I Yes", "score": 2, "percent": 20,
  "text": "Just a moment", "score": 2, "percent": 20,
  "text": "Okay a moment", "score": 1, "percent": 10
]
```

`score` is the number of time it is occurred and the `percent` is the number of time occurred divided by the total number of sentences.

I am able to get the words after looping on `senetences` but get stuck after it.

```
const string = "moment";
const words = [];
senetences.map((a) => {
  const arrayString = a.text.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  const index = arrayString.indexOf(string.toLowerCase());
  words.push(`${arrayString[index - 2]} ${arrayString[index - 1]} ${arrayString[index]}`);
  words.push(`${arrayString[index]} ${arrayString[index + 1]} ${arrayString[index + 2]}`);
})
```

After that I got stuck how to find in the `senetences` array now.

```
const output = []
senetences.map((a) => {
    phrases.map((p) => {
    const index = a.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(p)
    if (index !== -1) {
        output.push(a.text)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: What if you got a senetence as: `"A moment ago, then ... "` where _"moment"_ word in  2nd (indexof) place, what is the output then ? like: _"A moment ago"_ or _"moment ago, then"_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the strings and counts in an object:

```js
function f(search, length, sentences) {
  const words = sentences.reduce((acc, { text }) => {
    const arrayString = text.replaceAll(/\.|,/g, '').split(' ');
    const index = arrayString.findIndex(el => el.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase());
    if (index >= length) {
      const key = arrayString.slice(index - length, index + 1).join(' ');
      acc[key] = (acc[key] ?? 0) + 1;
    }
    if (index < arrayString.length - length) {
      const key = arrayString.slice(index, index + length + 1).join(' ');
      acc[key] = (acc[key] ?? 0) + 1;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})

  return Object.entries(words)
               .map(el => ({ text: el[0], score: el[1], percent: 100 * el[1] / sentences.length }))
               .sort((l, r) => r.score - l.score);
}

const sentences = [
  {"text": "And a moment I Yes."},
  {"text": "Wait a moment I Yes."},
  {"text": "And a moment I Hello, Guenta, trenteuno."},
  {"text": "Okay a moment. Hello. Perfect."},
  {"text": "And a moment."},
  {"text": "And a moment I Hello, Guenta, trenteuno."},
  {"text": "Just a moment in Quinta trenteuno."},
  {"text": "And a moment in Quinta trenteuno."},
  {"text": "Wait a moment I Hello, Guenta, trenteuno."},
  {"text": "Just a moment in Quinta trenteuno."}
];

console.log(f('moment', 3, sentences));
```

Comment: Just as we made it like 2 words before and after the `moment`, can we make it 3 or 4 or 5 as the user enters

Comment: @Profer Yes, I added a variable for this.

Comment: This is almost perfect... Just two things... if I search for `a moment` is should give me the result [see](https://jsfiddle.net/8539xs7y/2/)

Comment: @Profer Please remember: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service where you list your requirements and order code. You posted input, expected output, your code and a description. This answer solves the problem. You changed the requirements and I fixed the answer. But you should first try it yourself and ask a question about a specific problem you're struggling with.

Comment: @Profer You are splitting the sentences into space separated substrings and then you're searching for a search key. Of course, this won't work with `a moment`. You have to rethink the approach. You can first search for the search term, then split the string before and after the search term.

Answer (score 0):

This function should work, i added a precision parameter, to set how many words you want to use in your search, and added some code to replace all non text characters in the sentences.

```js
function searchAndScoreWords(sentences,searchPhrase,precision){
    //construct wordsArray
    const wordsArray = [];
    sentences.map((sentence) => {
      const arrayString = sentence.text.toLowerCase().replace(/(\.)|(\,)|(')|(\!)|(\?)/g,'').split(' ');
      const index = arrayString.indexOf(searchPhrase.toLowerCase());
      if(index!==-1){
        //if enough words before the search pharse push the words before phrase to array
        if(index>=precision-1){
            let words = [];
            for(let i=index-precision+1;i<=index;i++){
                words.push(arrayString[i]);
            }
            wordsArray.push(words.join(' '));
        }

        //if enough words after the search pharse push the words before phrase to array
        if(index<=arrayString.length-precision){
            let words = [];
            for(let i=index;i<=index+precision-1;i++){
                words.push(arrayString[i]);
            }
            wordsArray.push(words.join(' '));
        }
      }
    })

    //generate scores 
    let output = [];
    for(let i=0;i<wordsArray.length;i++){
        let occurrences = 0;
        for(let j=0;j<wordsArray.length;j++){
            if(wordsArray[i]===wordsArray[j]){
                occurrences++;
            }
        }
        if(!output.find(e=>e.text===wordsArray[i])){
            output.push({
                text:wordsArray[i],
                score:occurrences,
                percent:occurrences/sentences.length*100
            });
        }
        
    }

    return output;
}
const sentences = [
    { "text": "And a moment, I Yes." },
    { "text": "Wait a moment' I Yes." },
    { "text": "And a moment? I Hello, Guenta, trenteuno." },
    { "text": "Okay a moment. Hello. Perfect." },
    { "text": "And a moment." },
    { "text": "And a moment! I Hello, Guenta, trenteuno." },
    { "text": "Just a moment in Quinta trenteuno." },
    { "text": "And a moment in Quinta trenteuno." },
    { "text": "Wait a moment I Hello, Guenta, trenteuno." },
    { "text": "Just a moment in Quinta trenteuno." }
  ]

console.log(searchAndScoreWords(sentences,"moment",3));
```